# why I am not getting the actual sound measure unit in decibel?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I am programming an application that measures sound in decibel. the application running proper but it not provide the actual decibel sound value same with other provide approximate same but I need actual same value .what property I have to change for this.

```
    var maxDecibelDegree: CGFloat = 100
    var minDecibelDegree: CGFloat = 40

    fileprivate var secondPerDecibelCheck = 0
    fileprivate var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    fileprivate var levelTimer = Timer()
    fileprivate var lowPassResults: Double = 0.0
    fileprivate var decibelArray = [CGFloat]()
    recorder.updateMeters()
    var level : CGFloat!
    let minDecibels: CGFloat = -80
    let decibels = recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)
    if decibels < Float(minDecibels)
    {
        level = 0
    }
    else if decibels >= 0
    {
        level = 1
    }
    else
    {
        let root: Float = 2
        let minAmp = powf(10, 0.05 * Float(minDecibels))
        let inverseAmpRange: Float = 1 / (1 - minAmp)
        let amp = powf(10, 0.05 * decibels)
        let adjAmp: Float = (amp - minAmp) * inverseAmpRange
        level = CGFloat(powf(adjAmp, 1/root))
    }
    level = level * self.maxDecibelDegree + self.minDecibelDegree
    let degree: CGFloat = level/(self.maxDecibelDegree - self.minDecibelDegree)
    let radian: CGFloat = level*CGFloat(M_PI)/180
```